# Select Parent and Child Records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How do i select all the employees of a company and its child companies?

Using SQL Server 2008

**Employee**

```
Id | Name | CompanyId
```

**Company**

```
Id | Name | ParentCompanyId
```

Example:

1   Microsoft  0

2   Microsoft India  1

3  Microsoft Spain  1

I have this below query which gives only employees from Microsoft and not from Microsoft India & Spain.

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM Employee WHERE CompanyId=1
```

I am not good in SQL. Help me on this.

Comment: You can use a [recursive CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx).

Comment: @TimSchmelter i think Union All is helping me simply and I see it is wrapped with CTE. Over all Union ALL wil be the perfect i guess

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a CTE to build the company hierarchy, then join this back to the Employees table:

```
with CompanyHierarchy as
(
  select Id
  from Company
  where Id = 1
  union all
  select c.Id
  from Company c
    inner join CompanyHierarchy ch on c.ParentCompanyId = ch.Id
)
select e.*
from CompanyHierarchy ch
  inner join Employees e on ch.Id = e.CompanyId
```

[SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ed304/1).

You can also substitute a `CompanyId` variable into the anchor portion of the CTE if you want to parameterize the statement:

```
with CompanyHierarchy as
(
  select Id
  from Company
  where Id = @CompanyId
  union all
  select c.Id
  from Company c
    inner join CompanyHierarchy ch on c.ParentCompanyId = ch.Id
)
select e.*
from CompanyHierarchy ch
  inner join Employees e on ch.Id = e.CompanyId
```

[SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b27245/2), now with added hierarchy levels.

Comment: As is the way of the internet, the SQL Fiddle link is broken

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
   employee.name,
   company.id 
FROM employee
INNER JOIN company 
On employee.companyId= company.id
WHERE company.id IN (1,2,3)
```

Answer (score 1):

And it is correct for the query as you are asking only for the records whose company id is 1.

You have to write your query something like this.

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM Employee WHERE CompanyId in (SELECT Id FROM Company)
```

Now I have tried the above, which does what your given query is required to do. But for the desired results on the basis of Comapny/ParentCompany, please try the following query.

```
SELECT e.Id, e.Names FROM Employee e WHERE e.CompanyId = 1 
    or e.CompanyId in (SELECT c.Id FROM Company c where c.ParentCompanyId = 1)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is what i initially tried.. But not sure is this right approach with performance

Comment: For performance I'm afraid you have to check it. I will also look into it if I can find a better approach. Certainly depends on the amount of data. If you are not processing 10s of thousands of records, then I think you would be alright. Will check again though. Thanks